# How can FQL retrieve deleted post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I was wandering what Facebook Query Language (fql) query to use in retrieving deleted POST or Hidden Post and comment.

I have done lot of search but not successful

Comment: If it's deleted or hidden, you can't retrieve it.